# The approval framework is not displayed for users in Azure AD B2C. (User Consent)

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-api-management

i am currently implementing a "System-of-Systems" authentication architecture in Azure Active Directory B2C (AAD B2C). In these scenario there is an initial SSO application that redirects the user to a general dashboard. The dashboard should enable the user to use additional services (service applications). (For example a tile view)

To use these additional services, the user must grant explicit permission for each external service. With this delegated permissions, the user authorizes the service to access certain data (for example, IoT data or personal data).

These [AAD B2C application](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad) is characterized in this scenario by a client and backend application (api) (for each service). The client application contains scopes (delegated permissions) from the backend application, which are stored as a JWT validation - Policy in each Azure API Management endpoint.

Authentication against these assigned backend scopes already works with the Microsoft Login Provider (Identity Provider), but not with the local Identity Provider (for E-Mail).

---

**Here: [My Scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScBmM.png)**

I changed the access level from Admin to User in the application manifest: ([Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAERH.png))

---

Microsoft Access Panel [(works here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUDO6.png))

**My Problem the Local Idenitity Access Panel for users (that doesn't works) -> should look like this: [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/active-directory/develop/consent-framework) ([consent dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/active-directory/develop/media/consent-framework/consent.png))**

---

For the following request:

```
https://[tenant].b2clogin.com/[tenant].onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_SignUpAndSignIn&client_id=xxxxx-xxx-xxxxxx&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms&scope=openid https://[tenant].onmicrosoft.com/backend/Backend.Read&response_type=id_token token&prompt=login
```

... I always get the following error message:

```
AADB2C90205: This application does not have sufficient permissions against this web resource to perform the operation.
```

The approval framework is not displayed for the user, therefore the request is rejected by insufficient permissions.

Do you know how to solve this problem? Are there any walkarounds or configuration options?

Thank u & Best regards

Comment: hey @fasol did you ever figure this out? i am just as  confused as you. what is the purpose of broadly grandint admin permission for something that the user should clearly be in control of?

i have not made any progress on this

Comment: Hi @vampiire. The Azure AD B2C does not support the self-control of the user. Only for the administrator. I solved this as follows: The scopes are now automatically assigned in AD B2C (over a common app registration) for all users and in a separate token broker I store and orchestrate the actual scope reference. In a Storage Account (Meta) and Key Vault (Refresh Token) the information will be persisted. 
`Table in a storage account (managed by the broker): consented_user = app_id + user_id; services = app_id, checksum, scopes. ` I store the refresh tokens in a key vault for

Comment: @vampiire I store the refresh tokens (for each service) in a protected key vault, so that the service can independently request the new token via the broker instance. Service APIs are provided for the requests. -> `borker_url/apps/{user-id}`, `borker_url/give_consent/{app-id}/{user-id}`, `borker_url/token_for/{user-id}` - On the broker instance the AD-Auth is then requested with the assigned and specified scopes.

Answer (score 0):

You missed some scopes of your application. Navigate to **Applications (Legacy) -> API access**, the `scope` need to add all scopes that you select.

[image]
The scopes that you defined are in **Published scopes**, you could add `Full Scope Value` in the URL.

[image]

---

This is my URL, and it works well:

```
https://[tenant].b2clogin.com/[tenant].onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_SignupSignin&client_id=xxxx&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&scope=openid offline_access https://[tenant].onmicrosoft.com/api/demo.write https://[tenant].onmicrosoft.com/api/demo.read https://[tenant].onmicrosoft.com/api/user_impersonation
&response_type=id_token token&prompt=login
```

[image]

For more details, you could see [a tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-single-page-app-webapi?tabs=applications%2Capp-reg-preview) and [implicit flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/implicit-flow-single-page-application).

Comment: Thanks! I will get a general token back for this auth-request. The problem is, if I assign the scopes via Application (Legacy), the tenant admin will automatically agree to them (Granted-For-xx).

Implicitly the admin is given the permission to access these scopes (Apis) for the user. However, the user must actively agree to the scopes ( permissions) in an access panel. This is done from the context of the DSGVO data protection regulation for each individual external service.

The user should agree to the service later in the access panel and not the admin for all users. (concent dialog)

Comment: @fasol If you use **App registrations**, the scopes need to include all permissions(grant for xx). It is unachievable that the users actively agree to the scopes in Azure AD B2C(the [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/consent-framework) is AAD). If the permission is not `grant admin consent`, then there is the error message: *The scope 'xxx' provided in the request is not supported*.

Comment: The sample contains the option that the user can actively agree: _6.) As an administrator, you can also consent to an application's delegated permissions on behalf of all the users in your tenant. Administrative consent prevents the consent dialog from appearing for every user in the tenant...._ --> The assignment of scopes to the application is still set up by the administrator in my scenario. However, the logged-in user should be shown an access (consent) panel (like for every iOS or Android app) where he can allow an individual application to access his personal data.

Comment: @fasol The sample is just used for AAD. But AAD B2C does not support this approach.

Comment: Why it works for the Microsoft Identity Provider in the AAD B2C context? Here is an example --> `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&scope=openid offline_access https://[tenant].onmicrosoft.com/backend/Backend.Read https://[tenant].onmicrosoft.com/backend/WriteSensor
&response_type=id_token token&prompt=login` --> [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUDO6.png)

Comment: @fasol Because this URL `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`  is Azure AD(AAD). But `https://[tenant].b2clogin.com/[tenant].onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` is Azure AD B2C.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We are now planning to develop our own token broker that uses the authentication from Microsoft Azure AD B2C by an Azure Function. At the broker level, the access of each individual service is controlled by the UserId and ClientId `userId/clientId`. For each service, the scope structure, data protection declaration and description is stored in a database.
I will give a feedback again.
Thanks u very much!

Comment: Hi fasol. I'm in a similar situation like you and would love to hear if you found a solution or went with your described token broker.